# How to use dates in comparison operators

Tags: bash, shell, sh

If I have the following two variables, how can I use them in a comparison operator? EX: -ge- OR -lt in an IF statement stating if one date is greater or less than the other?

```
 startdate=`date -r log.txt`
 enddate=`date -r logfiletest.txt`

echo $startdate
Tue Apr 25 13:07:44 MDT 2023

echo $enddate
Tue Jun 20 09:34:04 MDT 2023
```

Thank you

Comment: As first step I suggest to use `date +'%s' -r file.txt` with GNU date.

Comment: Convert the date into _seconds after epoch_. This gives you integers. Use integer comparision to compare them.

Comment: Also, for files specifically, getting the timestamp of the file and comparing timestamps is unnecessary. Bash has `[[ file1 -nt file2 ]]` (file1 newer than file2) and `[[ file1 -ot file2 ]]` (file1 older than file2) to compare file times directly.